# python - Gstreamer live video feed to webpage

Tags: html5-video, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

**What I am trying to do:**

I have a live stream coming from my raspberry pi and I would like to view it on a webpage being served from a server which consumes the stream from the r_pi. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Also It is preferred to have low latency.

**I have looked at:**

https://gist.github.com/vo/a0cc9313861888ad5180f442a4b7bf48

which works but there is a large latency and doesn't work on chrome. Any ideas?

This also is an option:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

But it uses mjpeg. I am curious if I can directly consume a stream either on the server or on the client.

I guess I can do client side consumption by having the server feed the client the html page directly (although I don't know the implications of having a gstream pushing video to a tcpserver [tcpserversink]).

Could I just take the stream convert it to a webm and feed this webm to the client?

Comment: have a look on [webrtc](https://webrtc.org/)

Comment: @vk_gst Any example on how to consume a gstreamer stream using webrtc?

Comment: @vk_gst here is an example: https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/building-a-raspberry-pi-2-webrtc-camera

Comment: have a read here https://github.com/centricular/gstwebrtc-demos

Comment: @vk_gst Thanks! I looked at this earlier, was very confused as to how it worked. Struggled for a bit and got everything to work exactly the way I wanted to and learned webrtc! Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to measure the latency? Are you using wired or wireless network connection? I worked on a similar application, but then I used UDP and GStreamer videosink for displaying video over wireless network. The latency is around 500-800 ms.  Do you think webrtc might reduce this?

Comment: @vk_gst hrmm, I also get latency, but I am using tcpserversink over wifi so this may be an issue. For my project <=1 sec of latency is okay I just needed a way to display the stream in a webbrowser and dont want to use mjpeg because I am using a raspberry pi. I am curious can you provide your pipeline for gstreamer?

Comment: udpsrc ->rtpbin ->decoder -> videosink